# iOS Remove Keychain Value

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I'm using the Keychain like so:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"LoginData" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:responseObject[@"TOK"] forKey:CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

And wish to remove (null the value) like so:

```
[keychain setValue:nil forKey:CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

However, i only see this:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key acct.
```

Like wise, when i use this:

```
[keychain setNilValueForKey:CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

I get this:

```
setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key acct.
```

I'm using apple's KeychainItemWrapper, How would i do this correctly?

Comment: usually you need to delete the item, you cannot update it with a `nil` value directly, the `SecItemDelete(...)` method will do the job for you without any crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general to delete an item, generate the query you will normally do to fetch it, then use "SecItemDelete".

Like this -

```
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [self getQueryForKey:key];
OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query);
if( status != errSecSuccess) {
    ...
}
```

If you're using the keyChainWrapper you can do -

```
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"LoginData" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychain resetKeychainItem];
```